# Add parent folder name to all the .jpg(Case insensitively) files

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have my directory:

```
Parent
    Sub folder 1
         xyz_Room.jpg         
         xyz_facade.jpg
         abc_Room.jpg
    Sub folder 2
         xyz_Room.jpg         
         xyz_facade.jpg
         abc_Room.jpg
    Sub Folder 3
         yolo_Room.jpg
         Sub sub folder 1
             xyz_Room.jpg         
             xyz_facade.jpg
             abc_Room.jpg
```

The no. of sub folders inside any folder is not fixed, so the operations needs to be done recursively.

What is to be done is to find all the .jpg files and append their parent folder name to them. It should now look like

```
Parent
    Sub folder 1
         Sub folder 1xyz_Room.jpg         
         Sub folder 1xyz_facade.jpg
         Sub folder 1abc_Room.jpg
    Sub folder 2
         Sub folder 2xyz_Room.jpg         
         Sub folder 2xyz_facade.jpg
         Sub folder 2abc_Room.jpg
    Sub Folder 3
         Sub Folder 3yolo_Room.jpg
         Sub sub folder 1
             Sub sub folder 1xyz_Room.jpg         
             Sub sub folder 1xyz_facade.jpg
             Sub sub folder 1abc_Room.jpg
```

Can someone please guide me how to do this? This is to be done on a ubuntu16.04 GPU machine using the terminal.

Comment: Good. What have you tried?

Comment: do you need python or bash tips ?

Comment: @s_vishnu 
find . -name *_Room.JPG -exec rename -nv -- 's|/(.*)/(.*)$|/$1/$1.txt|' {} +
But this renames as the parent directory folder instead i want to append the parent directory name.

Comment: @PRMoureu -  Both would work equally fine. I am happy with any of those.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I am going to give a solution in **Python**. Say you have the directory `Parent` in the same directory ass your `.py` script. The one below!

And directory structure is same as this,

```
rename_script.py
Parent
    Sub folder 1
         xyz_Room.jpg         
         xyz_facade.jpg
         abc_Room.jpg
    Sub folder 2
         xyz_Room.jpg         
         xyz_facade.jpg
         abc_Room.jpg
    Sub Folder 3
         yolo_Room.jpg
         Sub sub folder 1
             xyz_Room.jpg         
             xyz_facade.jpg
             abc_Room.jpg
```

This code should work. (In Linux)

**rename_script.py:**

```
import os

for folder in os.listdir("./Parent"):
    s=os.listdir("./Parent/"+folder)
    for file in s:
        os.rename("./Parent/"+folder+"/"+file,"./Parent/"+folder+"/"+folder+file)
```

Now,

```
os.listdir("./Parent")
```

This would list all the subfolders inside parent as a `list`. So for each folder

```
s=os.listdir("./Parent/"+folder)
```

The above would get files from those subfolders and store them in a list, output of this for one `subfolder` would be,

```
['xyz_Room.jpg', 'abc_Room.jpg', 'xyz_facade.jpg']
```

Finally for each of those files rename it using `os.rename(src,dest)` . This does the same,

```
os.rename("./Parent/"+folder+"/"+file,"./Parent/"+folder+"/"+folder+file)
```

> **NOTE:**`folder+file` --> `Sub Folder 1xyz_Room.jpg`

i.e I am creating a new string there which would be the `concatenation` of subfolder and filename.

Output:

```
Sub folder 1abc_Room.jpg  Sub folder 1xyz_facade.jpg  Sub folder 1xyz_Room.jpg
```

The same will be done for all the subfolder. Hope I was clear.

Comment: This will do for 1 layer of sub folders inside. There can be 5-10 layers of sub folders too.

Comment: you should've mentioned it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xargs mkdir <  Sub folder 1
```

Comment: mkdir: missing operand?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @KaustubhMundra I do not know,just put the name of your subfolder

Comment: Yes I know that for sure but that does not work this way

Comment: @KaustubhMundra It owrks for me on Ubutnu 16.04 from comand line.

Answer (score 0):

use find command to list all required files. and iterate over all files using for loop

```
for file_name in `find . -name '*jpg' -type f`;
do 
dir_name=`dirname ${file_name}`;
base_dir_name=`echo ${dir_name} | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1`;
base_name=`basename ${file_name}`;
mv ${file_name} ${dir_name}/${base_dir_name}${base_name}
done
```

Comment: I need to go recursively? This code does not do that I suppose?

Comment: Will there be more than 2 levels of directories (parent/Sub folder)? If so do you want to only append the directory containing the file?

Comment: @KaustubhMundra Does this help?